# Design pattern for private members access?

Tags: c#, oop

Let's use this simple example :

**Connect4Board.cs :**

```
public class Connect4Board
{
    private Box[,] _boxes = new Box[7, 6];

    public void DropPieceAt(int column, bool redPiece)
    {
        //Safe modifications to box colors.
    }        

    public Box GetBoxAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return _boxes[x, y];
    }
}
```

**Box.cs** :

```
public class Box
{
    public bool IsRed { get; private set; }
    public bool IsEmpty { get; private set; }
}
```

I want `GetBoxAt()` to return a box with read-only properties. However I want  my `Connect4Board` to be able to change boxes colors.

Let's assume that I don't want to use `internal` modifier at all.

My solution (quite ugly) :

```
public class Connect4Board
{
    private Box.MutableBox[,] _mutableBoxes = new Box.MutableBox[7, 6];

    public Connect4Board()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            {
                _mutableBoxes[x, y] = new Box.MutableBox();
            }
        }
    }

    public void DropPieceAt(int column, bool isRed)
    {
        //Safe modifications to box colors.
    }        

    public Box GetBoxAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return _mutableBoxes[x, y].Box;
    }
}

public class Box
{
    public bool IsRed { get; private set; }
    public bool IsEmpty { get; private set; }

    private Box()
    {
    }

    public class MutableBox
    {
        public Box Box { get; private set; }

        public MutableBox()
        {
            Box = new Box();
        }

        public void MakeRed() { //I can modify Box here }

        public void MakeYellow() { //I can modify Box here }

        public void MakeEmpty() { //I can modify Box here }
    }
}
```

Is there a good design pattern to make this more elegant ?

Comment: One option would be to not return entire `Box` objects to the user, but rather to only let them query about the status of a square. As well, instead of IsEmpty/IsRed, you could just create a single `enum` for the state of a square (`enum SquareState { Empty, Black, Red }`) and then return that in response to the user's query. (Note that this also ensures no illegal states.) Finally, you could make an `IBox` interface (which is public) and then make `Box` a nested class of `ConnectBoard` (which implemented `IBox`). You could then make your query method return an `IBox` to the user.

Comment: @dlev Should be posted as an answer.

Comment: If you want `Connect4Board` to be able to change the colors of a `Box`, then `Box' is not immutable.  Would it be acceptable if `Connect4Board` was able to assign a new `Box`, (with the new corrected colors) to a property of some other object that is typed as `Box`?

Comment: @dlev Concerning the first option, I want a more general solution which allows an object to return immutable objects while being able to modify them from the inside. The second option will work, but for some reasons I want the two classes to be separated : no `internal` access modifier nor nested classes.

Comment: You could explicitly implement some interface `IMutableBox` which would expose methods to mutate your box object. Consumers who wish to do that would have to cast `Box` to an `IMutableBox` to access those methods.

Comment: Make a `Game.Core` assembly and a `Game.UI` assembly. Make the modification methods internal to `Game.Core`?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I don't want to use `internal` modifier. The solution should work even if `Box` and `Board` are in two separated assemblies.

Comment: You should ask why a board is able to modify the internal bits of a box when no other consumer can? If you are unwilling to define a relationship between a box and a board there is no way to distinguish a board from anyone else consuming a box. There is no way to explicitly define and enforce the type of relationship you are describing. Any solution you implement will rely on a contract that is left up to the developer to enforce.

Comment: @SimonV.: Mind if we ask why you don't want an `internal` or nested class? It's not that you can't get around it, but that requirement seems kind of contrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You could create a wrapper around `Box` which is immutable. `Connect4Board` would use the `MutableBox` class internally but would expose `ImmutableBox` to consumers.

```
public interface IBox
{
    bool IsRed { get; }
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
}

public class MutableBox : IBox
{
    public bool IsRed { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmpty {get; set; }
    public IBox MakeImmutable()
    {
        return new ImmutableBox(this);
    }
}

public class ImmutableBox : IBox 
{
    private IBox innerBox;
    public ImmutableBox(IBox innerBox) { this.innerBox = innerBox; }
    public bool IsRed { get { return innerBox.IsRed; } }
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return innerBox.IsEmpty; } }
}

public class Connect4Board
{
    private MutableBox[,] boxes = new MutableBox[7, 6];

    public void DropPieceAt(int column, bool redPiece)
    {
        // perform modifications
    }

    public IBox GetBoxAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return boxes[x,y].MakeImmutable();
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

You could maybe use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) to achieve this?
Create an interface `IMutableBox`.

```
public interface IMutableBox
{
    void SetIsRed(bool isRed);

    void SetIsEmpty(bool isEmpty);
}

public class Box : IMutableBox
{
    private bool isRed;
    private bool isEmpty;

    public bool IsRed { get { return isRed; } }
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return isEmpty; } }

    void IMutableBox.SetIsRed(bool isRed)
    {
        this.isRed = isRed;
    }

    void IMutableBox.SetIsEmpty(bool isEmpty)
    {
        this.isEmpty = isEmpty;
    }
}
```

Now, in order to mutate `Box`, you would need to cast it to an `IMutableBox`.

```
var box = new Box();
var mutableBox = box as IMutableBox;
mutableBox.SetEmpty(true);
```

Comment: Nice solution! It would be nicer if making a `Box` mutable was "harder" though.

Comment: Sure, but it seems you don't want it to be "truly" mutable. If you go about it this way, you can continue to evolve other classes which mutate `Box` and at the same time, present a facade of immutability to consumers.

Comment: This makes me feel uncomfortable. Anything that allows modification of the internal state of what has been advertised as an *immutable* object after it has been instantiated allows misuse by clients that might screw up other clients whom are depending on that immutability. The fact that you have to use a new and different interface to get to these other methods doesn't help the client that expects the values to remain constant.

Comment: which is why I mentioned it's not *really* immutable. If you want a type to be open for modification from a separate type you're not really creating an "immutable" type and should be ready to design things around that.

Comment: @Charles Bretana You are totally right, sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant "read-only" not "immutable", thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of strategies you could use.

It's often useful to program to interfaces. The IBox interface below would not allow people to edit the box (without casting it to a `Box`), but still leaves your code simple.

```
public class Connect4Board
{
    private Box[,] _boxes = new Box[7, 6];

    public void DropPieceAt(int column, bool redPiece)
    {
        //Safe modifications to box colors.
    }        

    public IBox GetBoxAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return _boxes[x, y];
    }
}

public interface IBox
{
    bool IsRed { get; }
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
}

public class Box : IBox
{
    public bool IsRed { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }
}
```

Another approach would be to make boxes always immutable (like strings), and instead of modifying the states of your boxes, you just modify which box is in which location in your array:

```
public class Connect4Board
{
    private Box[,] _boxes = new Box[7, 6];

    public Connect4Board()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<7; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<6; j++)
            {
                // Notice how you're not changing a color, but assigning the location
                _boxes[i,j] = Box.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    public void DropPieceAt(int column, bool redPiece)
    {
        // Modifications to the top empty location in the given column.
    }        

    public Box GetBoxAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return _boxes[x, y];
    }
}

public class Box
{
    public bool IsRed { get; private set; }
    public bool IsBlack { get; private set; }
    public bool IsEmpty { get; private set; }

    private Box() {}

    public static readonly Box Red = new Box{IsRed = true};
    public static readonly Box Black = new Box{IsBlack = true};
    public static readonly Box Empty = new Box{IsEmpty = true};
}
```

Comment: I guess I just don't understand this question. With the first solution, there is nothing to prevent any other consumer from taking the return of `GetBoxAt` and making the required cast to modify it. With the second solution, isn't this the same concept as making an `enum` for the the BoxType? i.e. `BoxType.Red`, `BoxType.Black`, `BoxType.Empty`?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: The OP specified that he didn't want any internal or nested classes, which kind of ties my hands a little, but the first solution still teaches a good strategy, which is to program to interfaces rather than concrete types. Without making `Box` internal or private, a consumer could cast his `IBox` to a `Box`, but explicit casts like this are bad practice anyway, since they can't really assume that my implementation will never change to use some other type.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: The second strategy isn't much different than using an `enum`, but it keeps the API similar to the original post. Perhaps the OP had some reason he wanted to be able to check whether a `box.IsEmpty` rather than checking `box == Box.Empty`. Using a class provides more opportunities to add functionality to the objects in the future. But making it an `enum` would certainly be a valid solution, and may be the best one in this case.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to pick on your answer, I just wanted to highlight that even the best solutions are going to have issues because of the constraints placed on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

WOuld this work for you?
Make Box Immutable, with static factory, and add static properties that return new boxes with various colors

```
  public class Box
  {
       private Box() {}
       private Box(Color color) { Color = color; }
       public static Box Make(Color color) { return new Box(color); }
       public static Box RedBox { get { return new Box(Color.Red); } }
       public static Box GreenBox { get { return new Box(Color.Green); } }
       public static Box BlueBox { get { return new Box(Color.Blue); } }
       //   ... etc.
   }
```

Comment: More generally, it seems to be common practice to use "with"-methods on immutable objects to create new instances with a slightly modified value, e.g. `public Box WithColor(Color color)`.

Comment: This maybe stupid question, but what do you mean by a "With" method ??   - Are you just talking about a naming convention for the factory ?

Comment: Maybe just make the box a struct then?

Comment: Or are you talking about a naming convention for a `Clone()` method that operates on an instance (not a static)object ?

Comment: @poke, unless `Box` needs to be parent for another derived class. that might be a good idea, howver, the Mutability (or Immutability) is independant of whther or not it is a class or a struct.

Comment: Re: "With"-methods: They are analogous to setters, but for immutable objects. For example, if you have an immutalbe `Contact` class it could have one of these methods for every property, `public Contact WithPhoneNumber(string phone)`, `public Contact WithEmail(string email)` etc... they would return a new Contact which only differs from the old one in that one property. Example: `fred.UpdateContactInfo(fred.CurrentContactInfo.WithEmail("newfred@example.example"));`.

Comment: ahhhh. I confess, this makes me feel uncomfortable.  Anything that allows modification of the internal state of an *immutable* object after it has been instantiated allows misuse by clients that might screw up other clients whom are depending on that immutability.  The fact that you have to use a new and different interface to get to these other methods doesn't help the client that expects the values to remain constant.

Comment: `WithEmail()` does not change the original object. It *can't* be changed, that's what immutable means. Again, as I wrote above, `WithEmail()` creates a *new* `Contact` that is exactly like the old `Contact`, except that it has a different email address.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `ReadOnlyBox` that can be a facade for your `Box` much like a `ReadOnlyCollection`.

```
[Flags]
public enum BoxState
{
    Empty = 0,
    Red = 1 << 0,
    Black = 1 << 1
}

[Flags]
public enum BoardColor
{
    Red = 1 << 0,
    Black = 1 << 1
}

public interface IBox
{
    BoxState State { get; }
}

public class Box : IBox
{
    public BoxState State { get; set; }
}

public class ReadOnlyBox : IBox
{
    private readonly IBox _box;

    public ReadOnlyBox(IBox box)
    {
        _box = box;
    }

    public BoxState State { get { return _box.State; } }
}

public class Connect4Board
{
    private const int _boardWidth = 7;
    private const int _boardHeight = 6;
    private Box[,] _boxes = new Box[_boardWidth, _boardHeight];

    public void DropPieceAt(int column, BoardColor color)
    {
        for(int height = 0; height < _boardHeight; height++)
        {
            if(_boxes[column, height].State != BoxState.Empty) continue;

            _boxes[column, height].State = (BoxState)color;
            break;
        }
    }        

    public IBox GetBoxAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return new ReadOnlyBox(_boxes[x, y]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let the C# compiler assign values for your enums (even bitfield enums). That shifting is entirely unnecessary.